# Find SVG polygon's points and add handles (circles)

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg

I have a number of SVG polygon shapes which need handles (circles) added at every point. I can of course add these circles manually like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
     viewBox="0 0 800 800" style="enable-background:new 0 0 800 800;" xml:space="preserve">
<style type="text/css">
    .st0{fill:#7BD0FF;fill-opacity:0.46;stroke:#3BB0FF;stroke-width:3;stroke-miterlimit:10;}
    .st1{fill:#FF4F4F;}
</style>
<polygon class="st0" points="266.14,191.92 471.86,127.15 530.52,302.39 666.14,388.49 550.33,633.06 225.76,580.49 359.86,363.34 
    153.38,388.49 "/>

<circle class="st1" cx="266.14" cy="191.92" r="8"/>
<circle class="st1" cx="471.86" cy="127.15" r="8"/>
<circle class="st1" cx="530.52" cy="302.39" r="8"/>
<circle class="st1" cx="666.14" cy="388.49" r="8"/>
<circle class="st1" cx="550.33" cy="633.06" r="8"/>
<circle class="st1" cx="225.76" cy="580.49" r="8"/>
<circle class="st1" cx="359.86" cy="363.34" r="8"/>
<circle class="st1" cx="153.38" cy="388.149" r="8"/>

</svg>
```

However, I need to do this for hundreds of points, and entering the coordinates for the circles manually seems inefficient when the coordinates already exist in the form of polygon points.

How do I detect the existing polygon's points and place a handle at each one? It seems like it should be really simple but I'm struggling to get anywhere with it.

Comment: Why don't you use a marker - that's what it's intended for (although there is an occasional bug)

Comment: @Michael Mullany: I guess the reason we can't use markers here is the OP needs draggable point handles. Afaik we can't add eventListeners to markers - or can we (would be pretty awesome)?

Comment: Ah - didn't realize the draggable part. You're right that rendered markers don't generate events (AFAIK as well at least).

Comment: @MichaelMullany I don't need them to be draggable. How would I go about setting up markers?

Comment: I'll add an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure – you can split the `points` attribute, then split each coordinate, and create elements from there.

Note that this will not take the polygon's transforms, etc. into account.

```js
const svg = document.querySelector("svg");
const poly = document.querySelector(".st0");
for (const p of poly.points) {
  const el = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'circle');
  el.setAttribute("class", "st1");
  el.setAttribute("cx", p.x);
  el.setAttribute("cy", p.y);
  el.setAttribute("r", 8);
  svg.appendChild(el);
}
```

```css
.st0 {
  fill: #7BD0FF;
  fill-opacity: 0.46;
  stroke: #3BB0FF;
  stroke-width: 3;
  stroke-miterlimit: 10;
}

.st1 {
  fill: #FF4F4F;
}
```

```html
<svg width="800" height="800">
<polygon class="st0" points="266.14,191.92 471.86,127.15 530.52,302.39 666.14,388.49 550.33,633.06 225.76,580.49 359.86,363.34 153.38,388.49"/>
</svg>
```

Comment: well, almost perfect. What if I want to control the styling of the circles? Is it possible to get it to create circles that have a class that I can set styling for?

Comment: In your previous question you asked for the inverse, a polygon to be draw over existing points (from you CMS) You then have to optimize all Points before you can draw (the biggest) polygon (using Graham Scan code): https://brian3kb.github.io/graham_scan_js/

Comment: Hi Danny, yes I am still trying to achieve the inverse for the same project as well, thank you for your help with that, I will take a look at Graham Scan.

Comment: Looking closer, it seems that "st1" is actually meant to be the class for the circles, but something is stopping the styling from working in your example, because the CSS says they should be red but they appear black.

Comment: @marklovin Fixed by using `setAttribute` instead of `className`.

Comment: You can also directly retrieve an array of point objects  from the polygon "points" property like so `const pts = [...poly.points]`. Pretty handy since polygons may arbitrarily separate point coordinates by spaces commas or even omit any separator if the x/y value starts with a minus. See [codepen example](https://codepen.io/herrstrietzel/pen/GRLEMQq?editors=1010). Frankly, I wouldn't take to much inspiration from adobe Illustrator's generic class names like `.st0` etc.) and assign more readable names manually

Comment: @herrstrietzel Oh, yeah, great point, I somehow forgot about the SVG DOM altogether there  Changed my answer to use `poly.points` instead.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how you would do it using a marker element

```html
<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
     viewBox="0 0 800 800">
  
 <defs>
   <marker id="point-circles" markerWidth="10" markerHeight="10" refX="5" refY="5">
   <circle class="st1" cx="5" cy="5" r="4" />
   </marker>
  </defs>
<style type="text/css">
    .st0{fill:#7BD0FF;fill-opacity:0.46;stroke:#3BB0FF;stroke-width:3;stroke-miterlimit:10;}
    .st1{fill:#FF4F4F; stroke: blue; stroke-width:0.5;}
</style>
<polygon class="st0" points="266.14,191.92 471.86,127.15 530.52,302.39 666.14,388.49 550.33,633.06 225.76,580.49 359.86,363.34 
    153.38,388.49" marker-start="url(#point-circles)" marker-mid="url(#point-circles)"/>

</svg>
```

Comment: Love this solution, it's so simple. I hadn't heard about markers before. Thanks for your help.